# Is it possible to overlay Span/UL/LI with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm just starting out with RaphaelJS (though I am familiar with SVG) and am attempting to implement custom overlays over a number of images.  My images are organized like so (ids are only for reference):

```
<div id="parent">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a>
           <span id="imageholder">
              <img>
```

with 6 `<li>` per `<ul>` and 10 `<ul>` per `<div>`

Based on specific data criteria, I would like to place a dynamic overlay over a subset of the images in this collection.  I've attempted a few different techniques:

1- Single Paper for the entire `div` contained in a sibling `div` to "parent."
2- 1 paper for each `span` as a sibling `span` to "imageholder."
3- Single paper for entire `div` as a child of "parent."
4- Single Paper for entire `div` as a top level child of `body`.

In all cases, the svg is below that which it is to overlay (or isn't visible at all).  I'm assuming that this has something to do with `inline` vs `block` display on the elements involved, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a CSS problem than a js/raphael problem.

The more robust solution would be creating a new paper as a sibling for each `span`, otherwise the click events won't register because the svg element will be on top of your anchors `<a></a>`.

Try with...

```
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a span.raphael {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

To reduce debugging complexity you should try to overlay the divs with static html first and then you can get Raphael to fill them its SVG/VML magic.

Comment: Precisely what I needed.  Thanks!